# App Crashed in the clearbtn TouchUpInside method in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
 <SearchBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                    x:Name="VendorSearch"
                    FontSize="25"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TextWhiteColor}"
                    Placeholder="Search Vendor Name"
                    Text="{Binding VendorSearchText, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    TextChanged="VendorSearch_TextChanged"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    WidthRequest="400" HeightRequest="50" />


void VendorSearch_TextChanged(System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SearchBar sb = (SearchBar)sender;
           
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sb.Text))
            {
                vm = (VM)this.BindingContext?.DataContext;
                if (vm != null)
                {
                    vm.VendorSearchCommand.Execute(sb.Text.Trim());
                }
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error {0}", ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
```

Xamarin Forms App Crashes when we click on the 'x' button to clear text .. Why ??

All Null checks are in place but still it crashes

Comment: What is the exception?  What does the stack trace or logs show?

Comment: FYI: Verify that the type of `(VM)this.BindingContext?.DataContext` is `VM`. A safer version of that line is `this.BindingContext?.DataContext as VM`. Then if type is wrong, you'll get null, instead of exception. HOWEVER, that won't be the cause of crash, given that you `try/catch` that code. Does `VendorSearchText` setter have any code in it? Perhaps an issue there.

Comment: "Crashed in the clearbtn TouchUpInside method  at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowException".     public Command SearchCommand
        {get
            {
                return new Command(async (obj) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if(obj == null)
                        {
                            
                        }
                       
                        
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                    }
                });
            }
        }

Comment: `Crashed in the clearbtn TouchUpInside method at ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ThrowException`What's the code of  method `TouchUpInside`?